# How to store images in server storage using node js and retrieve individual image links to be used in JSON responses?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, server

I am creating an application that where the admin can upload user details consisting of different fields like

```
{
email : "",
password: "",
firstName : "John",
lastName : "Doe",
age: "",
profilePhotoUrl : ""
}
```

As the admin uploads these details for an user - I'm storing these info into a mongodb collection. I want to store the profile photo in the server storage itself and somehow generate links for the images which I could add in the "profilePhotoUrl" field for each user while storing the it in mongodb.

***Note** - I don't want to store the image directly in mongodb.The backend application I'm developing would be used by both Web and Mobile clients.

The current solution that I can think of is using a storage service like cloudinary/google drive/S3. But I'm looking forward to do the same using the server itself **(Digital Ocean Droplet)**.

What would be an efficient way to approach this problem? Please help. I'm stuck here for so long!